# how to set run time env variable in webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, environment-variables

I am working on the react app, with webpack. I am now on the web dev.
the whole concept of the process.env is a little confusing.

as far as I know that the env (Environment variable) is the variable that is provided to the application to make the decision to run on the dev environment or production or etc.

what is not clear, is when it is available, is it available at the run time, when we are running the application with our development server, or its available at the compile-time when we are compiling our code.

and how do we use it, do we use the environment variable at the compile time to compile different flavours of the app, for prod/dev, etc.

or we build the app, but use the env variable in runtime to decide different flavors.

my requirement is I want to differentiate when the app is running locally so that I can set up some mock responses of the request, and for other environments, it can work without mock.

how can we achieve this?

Comment: At runtime a React app is running _in your users' browsers_, it has no access to the environment variables on the server. Env vars are applied at build time, I write about this here: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html

Comment: What we do where I work is use a different `.env` file in each environment along with the [DotEnv plugin](https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack) and run webpack on that environment when we need to deploy.